# How to include slider in wordpress theme development?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, customization

I am developing my own Wordpress theme and I want an image slider on it. I don't want it to be hardcoded, so the user should be available to change images in the admin panel. I decided to give a chance to Nivo Slider Plugin. 
So far so good, but how to tell my theme "Use this plugin and place the slider on that specific place"? On the other hand I've read somewhere that it is not good practice to use plugins for developing a theme. So I am little bit confused how to accomplish my goal? I am pretty new in Wordpress and some directions and advices will be really useful for me.

Comment: use [TGMPA](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I can advise you to use [Revolution Slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380), which is for me the best slider plugin in the universe !